# Laravel - Connection Refused via Scheduled, but not Manual

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a number of scheduled jobs that run every fifteen minutes, which are all set to run at the same time, so Laravel queues them up to run one after the other.

If I run the jobs via command line, they always complete without issues.  For example;

```
php artisan job:one && php artisan job:two && php artisan job:three
```

However, recently when these are run automatically by Laravel, `job:two` and `job:three` fail part the way through with a `Connection refused` error;

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: update `table` set `field1` = 1, `field2` = 7.36, `field3` = 3.6, `table`.`field4` = 2021-11-21 20:16:29 where `id` = 1126)
```

I've enabled `general_log` and `slow_log` on MySQL, so all queries that have been executed are stored in the `mysql` database, however I cannot find any of the queries relating to the above.  Further investigation seems to show that no queries are being run, so I can't understand why some scheduled jobs are failing to connect to the database, yet running manually connects fine.

Nothing shows in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are cron and PHP CLI running the same version of PHP?

Comment: @GilesBennett yes, both running PHP 8.0.13

Comment: OK, so...unlikely to be a permissions issue (wrong user) if one is working but the other two are not. I'm slightly perplexed by the error message - how come field1, field2 and field3 are shown as such, but field4 is shown as `table`.`field4` - ie. with the table name? And the date field, since it contains white space...should that be encapsulated?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in schedule function in Kernel Class

```
$schedule->command('job:one')->withoutOverlapping(2)->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . '/logs/queue-jobs.log');
$schedule->command('job:two')->withoutOverlapping(2)->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . '/logs/queue-jobs.log');
$schedule->command('job:three')->withoutOverlapping(2)->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . '/logs/queue-jobs.log');
```

Comment: I already use withoutOverlapping and it makes no difference.  This is to stop jobs from overlapping if the job is still running, which it isn't.

sendOutputTo just outputs the same error that I am receiving via email; `Connection refused`

Comment: are you tried  to put this in schedule function ?

Comment: Yes, they are already in the schedule function